# Add actions to JPopupMenu options

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, jpopupmenu

I have a class that extends JPanel and implements MouseListener. In this class, if the panel is clicked the following two functions are executed:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    displayExitPopup();
}

private void displayExitPopup() {
    JPopupMenu exitPopup = new JPopupMenu();
    exitPopup.add("Exit Game");
    exitPopup.add("Cancel");
    exitPopup.show(this, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
}
```

This all works fine and the popup displays the 2 options as it should.

Now I am trying to perform actions when either of the two options in the popup menu are clicked - `System.exit(0)` if `Exit Game` is clicked, and the popup menu to close if `Cancel` is clicked. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the [JavaDocs for `JPopupMenu#add(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPopupMenu.html#add-java.lang.String-), you will find that it's a convenience method which returns a `JMenuItem`, you should then be able to add an `ActionListener` to it

Take a look at [Bringing up a PopupMenu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for more details

Having said that, I would instead, encourage you to make use the `Action` API which will allow you to create self contained units of work, which also provide the information needed to create the `JMenuItem` used by the `JPopupMenu`

Have a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

You should also be using `JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu` instead of trying to use a `MouseListener`, as different platforms have different triggers for a popup menu and it's complicated and ugly real quick

Answer (score 3):

When adding a item to `JPopupMenu`, you get a `JMenuItem`. On this object, you can call [`addActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)) to add a action listener, like you have with a `JTextField` or a `JButton`.

```
exitPopup.add("Cancel").addActionListener(e-> {
    // do something
});
```